# How does a voltage divider work?

Tags: impedance, voltage-divider

I have a simple question regarding the voltage divider.

Let's say we have the case as in the image below:

[image]

I know the formula for the division of voltage at \$V_{out}\$.

My question is what happens if \$Z_2\$, or the second impedence becomes 0? The formula says the output voltage and the input voltage should be the same, but intuitively I don't understand how they could be the same.  Shouldn't the output voltage be a little less than the input, even if there is no second impedance, just because of the presence of that first one. Why is this not the case?

Comment: Have you tried Ohm’s law and KVL?

Comment: From ohm's law, if Z_2 is zero then V_out is also zero.

Comment: Energy will take the path of the lowest impedance. So Vout will be 0. If you say Vout has a resistance of Rout, two parallel resistances exist. 1/Rtot = 1/R2+1/Rout. You can’t divide by 0, but say its like 0.00001… Rtot wil be 0 also.

Comment: @RemyHx no it won't. Energy will distribute itself around the various paths as a function of their various conductances. Ask yourself; will a 10 k resistor in parallel with a 10.1 k resistor hog all the current, power and energy?

Comment: I have the feeling you mean the case when  Z2 is absent (infinity)...

Comment: @Andyaka if R2 is 0 (gone, so practically a short). Or what do you mean with no it won’t?

Comment: Energy (current squared) **will not** (exclusively) take the path of the lowest impedance @RemyHx

Comment: @Andyaka no it always does haha. Like in your example: if with a parallel situation of 10k and 10.1k: it also will take the path of lowest impedance. Only this time lowest is taking both paths, then it is lowest. Like 10k or 10.1k is higher than the shared path: 5k. If R2 is 0 and Rout is for example 10k. The parallel impedance is? 0. Energy will always take the lowest impedance path.

Comment: One path has lower resistance than the other so you can't say both paths are the path of lowest resistance because that makes no sense. It appears you are trying to squirm out of your error.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is what happens if Z2, or the second impedence becomes 0? The formula says the output voltage and the input voltage should be the same,

No, if Z2 becomes 0, the output will be 0.

Answer (score 0):

The 'formula' for the output of an unloaded voltage divider as shown is Vout/Vin = Z2/(Z1+Z2) so if Z2 = 0 the output will be zero, provided only that Z1 \$\ne\$ 0.